# Connecting llvm with Clion

Tags: c++, llvm, clion

I was trying to connect with my Clion. First, using [the guid](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#quick-start) I created a folder that contains cash:

```
$ mkdir mybuilddir
$ cd mybuilddir
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=... path/to/llvm/source/root
$ cmake --build .
$ cmake --build . --target install
```

I do not indicate type and path to the root because it does not matter.
My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(EAG_p)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(BUILD_ARCH "-m64")
set(TARGET_64 ON)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(EAG_p main.cpp)

llvm_map_components_to_libnames( llvm_libs
        Analysis
        Core
        ExecutionEngine
        InstCombine
        Object
        OrcJIT
        RuntimeDyld
        ScalarOpts
        Support
        native
        irreader
        )

target_link_libraries(EAG_p ${llvm_libs})
```

But that didn't work.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: When I say "Didn't work I mean that there was no error or something like this. But libraries of llvm didn't connect.

Comment: It is not clear what doesn't work and what "didn't connect" means.